# How to install Xilinx ISE 14.7 for Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: xilinx-ise, spartan, ubuntu-19.10

I have to work with a Spartan 3E family FPGA, my problem is that latest versions of Xilinx ISE does not support this boards. I made a quick search on google and I found that the last versión that supports Spartan 3E is 14.7 so I tried to install this one.

I'm working on Ubuntu 19.10, the Xilinx IDE I donwloaded was the 14.7 full installer for Linux from [here](https://www.xilinx.com/support/download/index.html/content/xilinx/en/downloadNav/vivado-design-tools/archive-ise.html).

Following the steps from [this guide](http://dreamrunner.org/blog/2012/09/12/install-xilinx-ise-on-the-ubuntu/) to install the .tar, in the step when you run the xsetup using

```
sudo ./xsetup
```

I get this error:

```
libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to install the libncourses.so.5 following some guides but I always get a 404 not found error when I try to download those libraries from the internet.

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 2):

Install libncurses5. Run this on the terminal.

`sudo apt-get install libncurses5`

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! Does this command works to you? It gives me an error. It looks like the libncourses online repositories have been deleted because is a 404 error.

Comment: Yes, it worked for me - @rafaelayllón. Does it work for you?

Comment: No, it didn't work for me, i get this error:

Comment: Err:1 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 libtinfo5 amd64 6.1+20190803-1ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:2 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 libncurses5 amd64 6.1+20190803-1ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/ncurses/libtinfo5_6.1+20190803-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/ncurses/libncurses5_6.1+20190803-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]

Comment: @rafaelayllón, I suggest you upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04. Then try, it worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Yes! I have just upgraded it and it works now. Thank you so much!! :D